# Different value behaviour between "let" and "var" when passed as arguments to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6

The difference between `let` and `var` is related to the lexical scoping and variable hoisting. But I have never seen how the values of variables change when passed as a parameter.
Example below:

```
for(let i =1; i<=5; i++){
  setTimeout(
    ()=>{ console.log(i) }, 
    i*1000)
}
```

prints the output [1,2,3,4,5] every second.

But when using `var`

```
for(var i =1; i<=5; i++){
  setTimeout(
    ()=>{ console.log(i) }, 
    i*1000)
}
```

prints [6, 6, 6, 6, 6] every second.

Comment: When using `let` in `for(let i =1; i<=5; i++)`, it creates a new `i` for each iteration of the loop that is scoped to just that iteration of the `for` block.  When using `var`, there is only one variable `i` that is shared by all iterations.  This is especially important when you insert a closure inside the loop and that closure executes later AFTER the `for` loop index has changed. With `var`, the `setTimeout()` only sees the terminal value of `i` which is `6` in your example.  With `let`, each call to `setTimeout()` has it's own value of `i` that is not affected by the rest of the iteration.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the answer/comment. This is what I was looking for. But how is this question exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable where only scope, hoisting and redeclaration is discussed?

Comment: It's just a question about scope which is the fundamental difference between `let` and `var` which is all explained in that other answer.  `let` creates a block scoped variable (inside the `for` loop).  `var` creates a function scoped variable (one variable for the whole function).